# Recyclerview automatically scroll up (a little) when update

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` in `CoordinatorLayout` in a `fragment`, there is a problem with `RecyclerView` in some situations, when I reload this `fragment` or calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, `RecyclerView` automatically scroll up a little (about 1 cm)!!!! And because of this, scrolling on `AppBarLayout` doe's not work! 
**It's on android 4.2.2**.
I googled it and cant find anything about this!

Comment: Do you have a focusable field on top, like edit text? If so, that might take the focus and come into view

Comment: I have faced same problem. you can use android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"  in your coordinate layout.

Comment: If that's the case, Deepak's solution will make your edittext un-focusable, which is not something you want. If not, his solution might even work.

Comment: @DeepakRathore solution worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Deepak Rathore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3295983/deepak-rathore) answer worked for me.

Adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to coordiante layout fixed my problem.